# Программа для управления БД в локальной сети

Tags: access, база-данных, java

Есть компьютеры, соединенные в локальную сеть. На одном из них стоит БД (Access). Необходимо написать программку, с помощью которой можно было бы добавлять, редактировать, удалять таблицы в БД с других ПК. Также необходимо осуществлять поиск по данным в таблицах.
Подскажите какую-то статью или пример, пожалуйста.
А то Я даже не знаю, с чего начать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь заходит об управлении любой БД из Java - то сразу надо бежать за [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver). Весь вопрос всегда в драйвере JDBC к той или иной базе.

Для MS Access - это драйвер (мост) JDBC-ODBC. Примеров подключения и управления в сети много, [к примеру](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2691&lngWId=2).

Comment: Спасибо огромное)